# Kivy error message

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on an application in Kivy that allows users to receive text messages from the application when they enter their phone number information. I tested the app and It worked for about a week. I created a twillio account and received a phone number. The application user is prompted to enter their phone number into my kivy app, and then I have to code set up so that they can receive periodic text messages and updates.

About 8 days ago I got this bizarre error message and I am completely stuck:
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref

That error message is displayed whenever I press the "get text updates" button. It used to promptly send a message then send a message every 30 minutes with Kivy's Clock.schedule method. Now I just get this error message. I have an exception handler so my app doesn't crash, but it definitely doesn't send messages anymore due to that error message. I am still able to send the user email updates. I haven't changed my code at all the past 8 days, so I don't know why it wouldn't be working.

Below is a slice of my code where I define variables that has my twilio information set up. I just omitted my accoountSid, authToken and myTwilioNumber for securitiy purposes, but in my actual source code they are there and valid, and again, worked until about 8 days ago:

`

```
enter code here`accountSid = ''
authToken = ''
myTwilioNumber = ''
twilioCli = Client(accountSid, authToken)
```

Next, Here is the part of my code that has an event scheduler that sends the user text updates:

"""This code below is enabling kivy to send the text to my phone, and I am just
    scheduling callbacks within the definitions. Will see if I am able to schedule the
    callbacks within the definitions with regularity so that the program works like
    normal. That means I should be able to schedule a callback for send_text2 within
    the definition of send_text1, and the callback for send text, 3, within the
    definition of send text2. I might have to change the time from 3600 to something
    lower in send text 2. I might have to change that to 1800 since the time might not
    start until send text 2 is called back. I might have to change the send text 3 time
    to 1800"""

```
def send_text1(self):

    try:
        Clock.schedule_once(self.send_text2, 1800)

        patient_number = str(self.ids.text_number.text)

        message = twilioCli.messages.create(body='You have 1 hour until we are ready to see you',
                                    from_=myTwilioNumber, to=patient_number)
    except:
        print("They did not enter a valid phone number")


def send_text2(self, *args):#Have to add another positional argument for it to work
    try:



         Clock.schedule_once(self.send_text3, 1800)
         patient_number = str(self.ids.text_number.text)
         message = twilioCli.messages.create(body='You have 30 minutes remaining until we are ready to see you',
                                from_=myTwilioNumber, to=patient_number)
    except:
        print("They did not enter a valid phone number")



def send_text3(self, *args):#Have to add a positional argument for it to work

    try:



        patient_number = str(self.ids.text_number.text)

        message = twilioCli.messages.create(body='We are ready to see you!',
                                from_=myTwilioNumber, to=patient_number)

    except:
        print("They did not enter a valid phone number")
```

In my .kv file I bind this root function to a button called get text updates. It worked for a couple of weeks, and only 8 days ago stopped working. Here is the full error message that I receive when I try to send text updates to the user:

From cffi callback :
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\AnnShawn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
     _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
 AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
They did not enter a valid phone number

The last line is my exception handler stating that the user didn't enter a valid number, but to test the app i'm using my personal cellphone number and I am entering it correctly. Again, I am doing the same exact thing that I did when the application was working, but am now receiving the above error message, and I don't know why. I've tried internet searches, reading, troubleshooting ect, and cannot find the error. I am fairly new to programming (3-months), and have been reading as much material as I can on Python and Kivy. I really cannot find why this stopped working so I came to stack as a last resort.

If anyone can help me i'll be extremely thankful. I hope that my question was detailed enough, because I am relatively new to stack, and I know that there's nothing more frustrating than a vague question.

Comment: For me it seems you must reinstall or upgrade some modules. Something like: pip install cryptography==2.0.3 pyOpenSSL==17.4.0

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I will try that later today and tell you if it worked. I really appreciate that.